# Segue is not performed for the first time

Tags: objective-c

I am having a button on which I am performing a segue. For the first time only when I click on that button segue is not performed but clicking once it works fine. Is this segue issue ???

Comment: Please add some code to evaluate issue

Comment: I just Push (segue through storyBoard) from a button to a ViewController. No coding is being done.

Comment: Check if Push segue property is correctly set in Source Viewcontroller to Destination ViewController

Comment: if i click several times on button then it starts working and segue is performed.

Comment: Please check this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

If it is really a button, you probably connected the wrong kind of action of the button to the segue, make sure you added "Touch up Inside".

If it is a cell you probably implemented didDeselect method instead of didSelect.

Comment: Its an button action (triggered segue) so we don't have to specify "Touch up inside".

Comment: @NupurGupta you can connect different kinds of events to a button, not only touch up inside.. the default when you drag from the button is in fact "Touch up inside". but if you go the connections tab you are going to see the others